Setting a pyenv virtual env in a script in zsh
I am using zsh, and I have setup .zshrc following this answer. I can use pyenv in the terminal.
However, if I call pyenv activate from a script
#!/bin/zsh
pyenv activate konsole

it fails with

Failed to activate virtualenv.
Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.

What should I do?

You need to perform the same operations as for your interactive shell. But you can also simply call /path/to/venv/konsole/bin/python etc directly.

I don't know Pyenv, but I would not be surprised if this provides a lot of functionality via i.e. functions or unexported shell variables. If you have put these definitions into your .zshrc, you would need to tell zsh that it should process this file. Hence, as a first experiment, I would turn the #! line of your script into #!/bin/zsh -i. If you don't get the error message then, you know the reason and can think of a better way of setting up the virtual environment.

It is necessary to access variables set up in .zshrc see this answer and so we need to use source <script-name>
So invoke the script using:
source <script-name>

and pyenv works
